# Can "and" be made a synonym of "&" when searching for a site name?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

I was trying to look up the "Board & Card Games" site in the site-switcher on the top bar, but I typed "Board and Card Games" and got no results.

I see now that pretty much all multi-topic sites use an ampersand in the title, but I think spelling out "and" is generally more common in titles.

Since the site-switcher search doesn't have to deal with query operators, could searching for "and" also be treated as searching for "&"?

Comment: Ok, I gotta ask: given there's only one site on the network with "board" in the name, why'd you keep typing?

Comment: By the time I had finished typing it out, the list of sites hadn't updated yet.  I suppose I could have stopped, but I'm used to having to type out most of the name and didn't think about this case.  Perhaps "English Language & Usage" vs "English Language Learners" is a better example, though there are still only two right now?

Comment: Stat wise: 13 sites have "&" in their name, none at all have "and". But lots of sites have "and" in their description, and the site switcher appears to search that field too.